# Calculator where it prints "Invalid number" each time user input anything other than a number

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, calculator, do-while

So when I first input anything other than a number the program prints "Invalid number 1" and it reloop. The problem is: When it reloop and I enter everything that the program expect and then enter any key to repeat, I get this problem: I insert anything other than a number but this time it doesn't print "Invalid number one" it skips it and print "Insert an operator: Error". 
Basically I want this calculator to ask me to enter numbers and the +/*/-// only but when I don't do that it should show me "Invalid num 1" or "Invalid operator" or "Invalid num 2" and then ask me to repeat until I input the correct form and then it goes to execute the next line and so on!

Note: I just started learning C and I want to put everything that I've learnt so far into this calculator. 
If/else/switch/printf/scanf/do...while/while/for/int/float/char/break/continue/
those are the things I've learnt so far!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int
main ()
{
  int num1, num2;
  int rst;
  char choice;
  int a = 43, b = 42, c = 45, d = 47;
  char i = a, f = b, g = c, h = d;
  char choix, n;
  do
    {
      printf ("\n\nPlease choice + or * or - or / for operater\n");
      printf ("\nPlease insert first number: ");
      scanf ("  %d", &num1);
      if (num1 != 0)
        {
          printf ("\nPlease insert an operater: ");
          scanf (" %c", &choice);
        }
      else
        {
          printf ("Invalid number 1");
        }
      if (choice == a)
        {
          printf ("\nPlease insert second number: ");
          scanf (" %d", &num2);
          rst = num1 + num2;
          printf ("%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, rst);
        }
      else if (choice == c)
        {
          printf ("\nPlease insert second number: ");
          scanf ("%d", &num2);
          rst = num1 - num2;
          printf ("%d - %d = %d", num1, num2, rst);
        }
      else if (choice == b)
        {
          printf ("\nPlease insert second number: ");
          scanf ("%d", &num2);
          rst = num1 * num2;
          printf ("%d * %d = %d", num1, num2, rst);
        }
      else if (choice == d)
        {
          printf ("\nPlease insert second number: ");
          scanf ("%d", &num2);
          rst = num1 / num2;
          printf ("%d / %d = %d", num1, num2, rst);
        }
      else if ((isdigit (choice) || isalpha (choice)))
        {
          printf ("Invalid operator");
        }

      printf ("\nDo you want to enter another pair of numbers(Y/N): ");
      scanf ("  %c", &choix);
      if (choix == 'n')
        {
          choix = 'N';
        }
    }
  while (choix != 'N');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program tells the user to input an operator, and then immediately after that (without reading in anything) it tells the user to input the first operand, and then it reads in that operand. And then you ask for an operator **again**, but only if the number isn't `0`. It's hard to tell what it's doing wrong because it's not easy figuring out what it's trying to do at all.

Comment: First, you should make a function only to read a number. `scanf` can be used for that, but it's a function full of caveats: see http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: No program that uses `scanf` and needs to check the input can be made to work without testing the return value from `scanf`. What's that? *"Returns the number of fields successfully converted and assigned."*